# How can I correctly align an image to the right edge of a "Label"?

Tags: c#, image, alignment, label

Using a standard Label I aligned my image to the right side.
However there is a small indent (marked in red) that I cannot remove.

[image]

So my question: Is there an easy way to correctly align/snap an image to the right edge of a label? Or do I need to edit the label paint method so I can manually draw the image?

The label in question sits inside a "Panel", the following is my code:

```
    label1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    label1.Image = global::TestProject.Properties.Resources.Header;
    label1.ImageAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
    label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 40);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer appears to be: No there is no easy way to correctly align the image.

The "PictureBox" seems like the preferred component for working with images, however the image can be correctly aligned by editing the paint method of the label:

```
label1.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.label1_Paint);
```

And the paint method:

```
    private void label1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Image image = global::TestProject.Properties.Resources.Header;
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        //Align to far right: label width - image width
        g.DrawImage(image, this.label1.Width - image.Width, 0);
    }
```